# porqué el decimal.TryParse me retorna en false

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
 decimal number;      

            if (decimal.TryParse(txtDiscount.Text, out number))
            {
                globalDiscount = number;
                doSum();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La cantidad de descuento global no tiene un formato correcto.1", "",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                txtDiscount.SelectAll();
                txtDiscount.Focus();
            }
```

Cuando ejecuto el programa me muestra lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto capturas de los valores que se están pasando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro identificar porqué entra al else, agradecería mucho su apoyo, de antemano gracias. DTB

Comment: porque esto "$300.00" no es un numero.. aunque vos lo pienses como numero, no es un numero.. el lenguaje no sabe que es $, entonces no puede transformarlo a numero... sacale eso, y va a funcionar...

Comment: Eso es un precio. Un número no tiene símbolos adicionales. Es un número a secas.

Comment: @gbianchi es un estilo numerico, exactamente Currency y vive en el namespace 
System.Globalizationhttps://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-6.0

Comment: @Picardia buenisima respuesta.. yo solo le respondi porque no le andaba su transformacion, cuando OP no entendia el porque...

Comment: @gbianchi np una vez mas despues de mucho tiempo vuelvo a ver tu perfil xD y ahora eres mod :0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comentan, el valor "$300.00" no es un numero, lo que puedes hacer es con una expresión regular quitar el signo de dolar y solo dejar los valores numéricos y con esto hacer el Parse, te quedaría así:

```
 var valor = Regex.Match(txtDiscount.Text, @"\d+\.*\d+").Value;

 if (decimal.TryParse(valor, out number))
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: con un replace seria mas rapido y mas seguro ;).. pero no esta mal esto...

Comment: Si, pero con esta expresión regular puedes quitar todos los caracteres que no sean numéricos.

Answer (score 6):

Puedes usar el constructor de TryParse que acepta el valor a convertir, el estilo numerico, el formato y la variable a expulsar.

[Documentacion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-decimal-tryparse(system-readonlyspan((system-char))-system-globalization-numberstyles-system-iformatprovider-system-decimal@))

Ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stringConSimbolo = "$300.00";
        var result = decimal.TryParse(stringConSimbolo, NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out var valorConvertido);
        
        if(result)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", valorConvertido);
    }
}
```

Live demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rn4IgI

Y si esa funcionalidad se repite a travez de la solucion simplemente creas un metodo de extencion para facilitar la conversion de esta manera.

Ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
                    
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var stringConSimbolo = "$300.00";
        Console.WriteLine(stringConSimbolo.ParseCustomCurrencyToDecimal());
    }
    
    public static decimal ParseCustomCurrencyToDecimal(this string stringConSimbolo) {
        return decimal.TryParse(stringConSimbolo, NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out var valorConvertido) ? valorConvertido : 0m;
    }
}
```

Live Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BZW0nf

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, me gustó mucho